# Difference between pass-by-reference & and *?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between passing-by-reference and using the C pointer notation?

`void some_function(some_type& param)`

and

`void some_function(some_type *param)`

Thanks

Comment: I doubt somebody is going to reproduce one of the 1000 tutorials and explanations that already exist here. Have a look at:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass a pointer to a variable in a subroutine call, the address of that variable is passed to the subroutine. To access the variable in the subroutine, the pointer has to be dereferenced.

When you pass a reference to a variable, the compiler takes care of obtaining the address of the variable when the variable is passed to the subroutine and dereferencing the variable in the subroutine.

Comment: That's definitly NOT a syntactic sugar. There are differences, as you may see from the other answers.

Comment: There are many subtle differences between the two as a reference is a alias. See below.

Answer (score 6):

- You can't get a NULL reference: this alone gives you lots of safety
- You can treat your reference as if it was an object: you can dereference it or whatever you need.

Basically you handle a safe pointer as if it was your own object.

Comment: you can easily get a null reference by dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Thats being defensive or paranoic??

Comment: It's usually more of a mistake: your reference points to an object that has been destroyed or has never existed. Infamous example: `std::vector<int> myVec; myVec.front();`... how you regret then, that `std::vector<T>::front` does not throw out_of_range!